# Bus ticket price in Salzburg (line 150)

Tags: public-transport, tickets, buses, austria, salzburg

I'm planning to travel to Hallstatt from Salzburg on Tuesday. They told me that I can go there by bus (150 line, Salzburg-Bad Ischl) and train (Bad Ischl-Hallstatt). I found the train and know the price of it (7.8 euro), but I don't know the prices of the buses. I read that I can buy the tickets from the bus driver.

The bus's station/stop is Salzburg Hbf (Südtiroler Platz). How much is it, if someone knows it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accord to the [Salzburger Verkehrsverbund](http://www.svv-info.at/en/home/), a single ticket from Salzburg to Bad Ischl costs 10.10 EUR:

[image]

You can indeed buy the ticket from the driver.

The [Austrian Federal Railways](http://www.oebb.at/en/index.jsp) quote a fare of 4.10 EUR for a single 2nd class ticket from Bad Ischl to Hallstatt:

[image]